# WCF The request failed with HTTP status 405: Method Not Allowed

Tags: wcf, http-status-code-405

I have a WCF service that has been hosted on a Windows Service and uses the BasicHttp endpoint to serve Windows Mobile devices that has been connected to it.

The problem is that with the Device Emulator. I can connect to the service and using it without any problems, but with an actual device. I receive the error:

> WCF The request failed with HTTP status 405: Method Not Allowed.

I have used following code to implement the service.

```
BasicHttpBinding basicHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
basicHttpBinding.UseDefaultWebProxy = false;

m_ServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IKooft), basicHttpBinding, "KooftService");
m_ServiceHost.Open();
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

Check your IIS extensions, particularly those for .wsdl are valid:

In IIS:

- Look at the properties for your site.
- In the Home Directory tab, click
  configuration.
- Click add (my path is
  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common
  Files\MSSOAP\BINARIES\SOAPIS30.DLL" )
- Set the extension to .WSDL and allow
  "Get" and "Post"
- Select "Script
  Engine" and "Verify That File Exists"

That should be it.

Comment: As I mentioned, it is hosted on a Windows Service application not IIS.

Comment: SOAPIS30.DLL is missing on my development box and I am experiencing a similar issue.  Do you have any idea where I can get that DLL from?  What SDK is it part of?

Comment: To answer my own question that DLL comes from the deprecated Microsoft SOAP Toolkit.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a WCF REST service, you should define your contract method like this:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
string CheckService();
```

Particularly note that `WebInvoke` attribute and `Method="POST"`.

Answer (score 0):

When using WCF you might also need to map the .svc file type to aspnet_isapi.dll in IIS.